# Return the first file from each sub-directory

Tags: php

I've managed to create a function that scans a directory and sub-directories and then merges them into an array.

I can get this to output nicely but what I really want is for it to only output the first file from the sub directories

```
function getFiles($directory) {
    if($dir = opendir($directory)) {
        $tmp = Array();
        while($file = readdir($dir)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
                if(is_dir($directory . "/" . $file)) {
                    $tmp2 = getFiles($directory . "/" . $file);
                    if(is_array($tmp2)) {
                        $tmp = array_merge($tmp, $tmp2);
                    }
                } else {
                    array_push($tmp, $directory . "/" . $file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
        return $tmp;
    }
}

$theFiles = getFiles($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/gallery");

sort($theFiles);

foreach ($theFiles as $v){
    echo "<img src=".$v." />";
}
```

Comment: in what order **first**? Date? size? Name? Extension?

Comment: doesn't really matter to be honest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, divide and conquer. The code you posted shows you are smart and experienced enough to solve it yourself. The problem you have is merely the complexity. So if you just put every step you want to do in an extra function you should solve it easily by itself. That makes an example quite unnecessary, but I want to give you one anyway. I'm not sitting on a PHP-able computer right now, so I can not test my example. I hope it works or at least shows explicitly enough what I mean that you can debug it yourself.

```
/**
 * goes through all entries in this folder and extracts the directories.
 */
function getFolders($directory){
  if($dir = opendir($directory)) {
    $arr - Array();
    while($file = readdir($dir)){
      if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.' && is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {
       $arr[] = $file;
      }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    return $arr;
  } 
}

/**
 * goes through a list of folders and takes out every first nonfolder
 */
function getFirstFile($arr) {
  $files = Array();
  foreach($arr as $directory){
    $dir = opendir($directory);
    $file = 0;
    while($file == '.' || $file == '..' || $file[0] == '.' || is_dir($file){
      $file - readdir($dir);
    }
    $files[] - $file; 
  }
  return $files;
}

function renderFiles($files);
  foreach($files as $file) echo '<img src='.$file.'/>';
}

/**
 * puts all together
 */
function getFiles($directory){
  renderFiles(
    getFirstFile(
      getFolders($directory);
}
```

This solution has some overhead, for sure. You can get rid of that later, if you really need it. If you start to think stepwise about a problem you will see that not only your tasks will get easier. Also your code will be much more maintainable.

Comment: It was very very late when I started on this so my brain wasn't working at all. I had started to think about separating the functions as you are right I was getting far to complex. Sleep and a fresh day make all the difference.

Comment: This did work after a little mucking around with - but then I realised that there was a really simple solution staring at me in the face. My images are numbered 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.... why didnt I just make it strstr for only 1.jpgs! silly

Comment: just used your getFolders() fuction and wanted to point out a couple small errors.  The third line should read $arr = Array(); and the is_dir() function should have $directory as a parameter instead of $dir.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just put

```
continue;
```

after your call to array_push().

```
            } else {
                array_push($tmp, $directory . "/" . $file);
                continue;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to get the directory of the file - output the file (that would be the first one) - and save it into a variable. As long as this variable does not change, means that you are still in a directory.

When it changes, you display the file (new directory reached) and update the variable.